# Read parquet file column by column

Tags: java, hadoop, avro, parquet

I have a parquet file containing archived data from an RDBMS table (so basically repetition level=0 for all values).  I need to read the file one column at a time. Basically here is the sequence I want to perform:
Read all the values from a table column in the parquet file -> write it to a TEXT file -> read all values from the next table column in the parquet file-> write it to another TEXT file.... and so on and so forth.

What is the most efficient way to do this in java?

PS: I chose parquet format (as opposed to avro) for archiving in the first place since parquet helps me achieve better compression in comparison to avro. Also, since my requirement is to read all values of a column at a time, my assumption is that doing so would be faster with parquet given the inherent nature of the format (columnar storage).

[EDIT]
Here's the code I am using to read the RDBMS table column by column. For the sake of simplicity, assume that all columns in the table contain String(Varchar) values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    try {
        ParquetMetadata readFooter = ParquetFileReader.readFooter(conf, path, ParquetMetadataConverter.NO_FILTER);
        MessageType schema = readFooter.getFileMetaData().getSchema();
        ParquetFileReader r = new ParquetFileReader(conf, path, readFooter);
        PageReadStore rowGroup = null;

        try {

            while (null != (rowGroup = r.readNextRowGroup())) {
                numRowGroups++;
                rows+= rowGroup.getRowCount();

                ColumnReader colReader = null;
                ColumnReadStore colReadStore = new ColumnReadStoreImpl(rowGroup,new GroupRecordConverter(schema).getRootConverter(), schema, "blah");
                List<ColumnDescriptor> descriptorList = schema.getColumns();

                //for each column
                for(ColumnDescriptor colDescriptor:descriptorList) {

                    //Get datatype of the column 
                    PrimitiveTypeName type = colDescriptor.getType();

                    String[] columnNamePath = colDescriptor.getPath();
                    columnName =Arrays.toString(columnNamePath);
                    colReader = colReadStore.getColumnReader(colDescriptor);
                    long totalValuesInColumnChunk =  rowGroup.getPageReader(colDescriptor).getTotalValueCount();

                    //For every cell in the column chunk
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalValuesInColumnChunk; i++) {

                        System.out.println(columnName+" "+colReader.getBinary().toStringUsingUTF8());
                        colReader.consume();

                    }

                } 

            }
        } 
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally {
            r.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading parquet file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of rows: "+rows);

}
```

Comment: Parquet isn't optimized to hold single columns. With that format, Avro or Parquet would be not much different

Comment: It would be also be a good idea to edit your question with what you tried. It doesn't need to be SQL, and why do you need to do it in Java? For example, Hive or Pig can read Parquet just fine

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure...i have attached the code that I am trying to read the parquet file in columnar fashion. I would think since parquet stores the same column chunks in an optimized way, the disk seeks and reads would be optimized leading to faster access. Curious to know the reasoning behind your claim "Parquet isn't optimized to hold single columns"(?)

Comment: It's optimized to hold multiple columns, not singular slices of them. My point is that if you have only one column, a row oriented format such as Avro wouldn't have much disadvantages

Comment: @cricket_007 To your second question, the simple answer is project deadline :) Implementation in Java would fit right into the current implementation. Pig or Hive would have some learning curve for me at this point. Having said that, are their any advantages(performance, better api support etc) of using Pig/Hive over Java?

Comment: Both are using Java under the hood. Loading a Parquet file and extracting a single column is maybe 3 lines of Pig or Spark. For Hive, you'd need to define a table over the file, as well as the destination, which you tagged sql and mentioned RDBMS, so I assume you used Sqoop to import the data? Did you make a Hive table with that? Why didn't you import single columns using Sqoop?

Comment: @cricket_007 In case the use case came across differently, just to clarify, the above code assumes that all columns are varchar, to facilitate discussion. Also, the table contains multiple columns. I need to dump values from each column into a separate text file. Are you suggesting that Avro's perfomance would be comparable? That would imply reading each row (~10 million) and for each cell of a row dump the value into the corresponding text file.

Comment: The "separate text file" (which would actually be binary file) can be Avro, Text, Parquet, ORC, etc. The only optimization you'll get from splitting columns is compression

Comment: @cricket_007 Okay...I think there's some misunderstanding here. Basically, my source parquet file is already a dump of a SQL table generated by another module. All I am doing is read the file, extract all values in every column and dump the data of that column into a text file. I would like to move this conversation to a chat(to avoid an extended comment thread) if you have any questions or inputs. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "SQL column" in Parquet. And I don't know how to read a Parquet file outside of the tools mentioned above that are built into the Hadoop distributions I use... From what I can see in your question, it looks fine. You're just missing writing to a file or actually getting a column